# Rails append not adding object to has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I'm getting weird behavior when trying to add objects via a has_many :through relationship.

My models:

```
Class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_to_team_histories
  has_many :team_histories, through: :player_to_team_histories
end
Class TeamHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_to_team_histories
  has_many :players, through: :player_to_team_histories
end
```

The code:

```
>>p = Player.first
>>p.team_histories.count
0
>>p.team_histories.append TeamHistory.create
>>p.team_histories.count
0
>>p.team_histories.push TeamHistory.create
>>p.team_histories.count
1
>>p.team_histories << TeamHistory.create
>>p.team_histories.count
2
```

Why does `append` not add the newly created `TeamHistory` to the `team_histories` array?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2.

**Update**

Posted an issue to Github:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7364

Comment: Nice question. I thought this was trivial, but I can't find any documentation for the append method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `append` is not an ActiveRecord method but passed through to the underlying (temporary) Array that represents `team_histories`. It may be a bug or oversight that this method is available but unable to properly save associations, but in the meantime you should just use `push` or `<<` for this purpose.